# Laravel API rewrite in Nginx Unable to open primary script

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Ok, i've been scratching my head for days now trying different combinations to get this damn thing working.

Im using a javascript frontend and I want to use Laravel as the backend API, loading it from the domains /api/ directory. I am using Nginx as the web server but i somehow my nginx config isnt working too well.

My config is as follows;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .reactproject.com;
    root "/home/reactproject/code";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location ^~ /api {
        alias "/home/reactproject/api/public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ @api;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }

    location @api {
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location / {
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/reactproject.com-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

The frontend loads perfectly, no problems there, but when i go to load reactproject.com/api/ i get the following error;

```
No input file specified.
```

If i check the logs, i am seeing this error;

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/reactproject/api/public/api/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.1, server: reactproject.com, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "reactproject.com"
```

No matter what i do, it keeps tacking /api/ to the end of the api's location alias.

All I want to be able to do is load my laravel API routes, through the /api/ directory of the reactproject.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename`

Comment: @RichardSmith That works for the welcome route only ... Any other routes brings up a 404 and trys accessing it root directory